# Applying .patch file in Yocto does not work

Tags: qt, build, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to patch a custom qt virtual keyboard from Yocto.

First of all I cloned the git repo of that keyboard, changed one file (just replace an old version of .otf by new one), committed the changes and created the patch file executing:

`git format-patch -1 <COMMIT_ID> -o patches`

In result I have an commit file inside /patches/ folder.
I have checked it by reverting the changes and `git apply <File.patch>` again. Everything looks fine.

The next step.

I have necessary ***qtvirtualkeyboard_%.bbappend*** file in ***/sources/meta-yogurt/recipes-qt/qt5/***.
I created new folder ***qtvirtualkeyboard*** and copied the ***file.patch*** there.

Than I modified ***qtvirtualkeyboard_%.bbappend*** and not it looks like:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += \
"file://0001-Update-font-file.patch;striplevel=0"

PATCHTOOL = "git"

PACKAGECONFIG = " lang-de_DE lang-en_GB lang-ru_RU lang-zh_CN \
lang-it_IT lang-ja_JP"
```

I tried to modify it with and without PATCHTOOL var and striplevel - it did not make any result.

And in the end when I build the image I receive the next error:

```
ERROR: qtvirtualkeyboard-5.9.8+gitAUTOINC+dc18b608b5-r0 do_patch: Applying '0001-Update-font-file.patch' failed:
can't find file to patch at input line 12
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From 5defffb3a8afaa8e254cd2cf551d6126ead74014 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Savchenko Serhii <s.savchenko@smissltd.com>
|Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 11:41:37 +0300
|Subject: [PATCH] Update font file
|
|---
| FontAwesome.otf | Bin 85908 -> 465076 bytes
| 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
|
|diff --git a/FontAwesome.otf b/FontAwesome.otf
|index 81c9ad949b47f64afeca5642ee2494b6e3147f44..7720e3739b64143d0a1dcb28fda78ac209afbcb8 100644
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you looked if you patch file was copied to the working folder of your recipe? Inside temp folder you can see which commands was executed. If you reproduce the same command in bash you can understand the failure reason.

Comment: From a quick look at your output, my first thought would be it looks like a path problem. It says "can't find file to patch". And your diff doesn't seem to specify a path: "diff --git a/FontAwesome.otf b/FontAwesome.otf". The font file doesn't go in the root folder of qtvirtualkeyboard, does it?

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov If I understand you correctly - I have found the patch file in the working dir. Full path is 
 _/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/qtvirtualkeyboard/5.9.8+gitAUTOINC+dc18b608b5-r0/0001-Update-font-file.patch_

Comment: @JarMan unfortunately it is in root folder. You can check it [here](https://git.phytec.de/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard/tree/). FontAwesome.otf

Comment: @UncleSav look inside log.do_patch and run.do_patch files in the temp folder. It is probably failed inside do_patch function

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov log.do_patch tells me almost the same what I described in a question and mentions the error "ERROR: Function failed: patch_do_patch". Inside run.do_patch I have only the python script for patching. Due to logs it fails somewhere (I will try to continue in the next comment)

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov`bb.note("Applying patch '%s' (%s)" % (parm['patchname'], oe.path.format_display(local, d)))
        try:
            patchset.Import({"file":local, "strippath": parm['striplevel']}, True)
        except Exception as exc:
            bb.utils.remove(process_tmpdir, True)
            bb.fatal(str(exc))
        try:
            resolver.Resolve()
        except bb.BBHandledException as e:
            bb.utils.remove(process_tmpdir, True)
            bb.fatal(str(e))
`

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov in this block after bb.note(). Copy-pasting the code looks weird here, sorry about that

Comment: I think you have problem with patch file. Have you tried to run `git am YourFile.patch`.

Comment: Your link for the virtual keyboard source shows something called `QtFreeVirtualKeyboard`. That is not the same as `QtVirtualKeyboard` that actually comes with Qt. Maybe you're trying to apply your patch to the wrong source tree?

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov I have tried to do this in the local cloned repo. When I created the patch. I applied it via `git am file.patch` and `git apply file.patch` - everything worked fine (for local repo)

Comment: @JarMan I will check the available recipes

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue here. In my case I built the patch via `git format-patch` in  `devtool` workspace. Then I used `devtool update-recipe <recipe-name>` to update the bb file. After running `bitbake <recipename>`,  I am facing the same error as mentioned above. Also in the `${S}` (source) directory there is a patches folder created and inside it there is the patch file and a series file. However the patch is also available in `../${S}` ie previous dir of source. This looks weird to me. I will try to look for the problem.